# Group by date from multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

first of all sorry for that title, but I have no idea how to describe it:

I'm saving sessions in my table and I would like to get the count of sessions per hour to know how many sessions were active over the day. The sessions are specified by two timestamps: start and end.

Hopefully you can help me.

Here we go:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfb62/2/0

Comment: Can you create a www.sqlfiddle.com example with your schema and dataset?

Comment: Active over the day, do you mean where both start and end dates were in the same day?  Or either start or end date?  Should be easy to do with COUNT operator.

Comment: For each hour starttime must be before and endtime must be after that hour. How can I use this in my where clause?

Comment: what will be your desired result then?

Comment: Base on this sessions I want to create a chart that shows how many players were online every hour of a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is rather hard in MySQL.  You can, however, get an approximation without too much difficulty.  The following counts up users who start and stop within one day:

```
select date(start), hour,
       sum(case when hours.hour between hour(start) and hours.hour then 1 else 0
           end) as GoodEstimate             
from sessions s cross join
     (select 0 as hour union all
      select 1 union all
      . . .
      select 23
     ) hours
group by date(start), hour
```

When a user spans multiple days, the query is harder.  Here is one approach, that assumes that there exists a user who starts during every hour:

```
select thehour, count(*)
from (select distinct date(start), hour(start),
             (cast(date(start) as datetime) + interval hour(start) hour as thehour
      from sessions
     ) dh left outer join
     sessions s
     on s.start <= thehour + interval 1 hour and
        s.end >= thehour
group by thehour
```

Note:  these are untested so might have syntax errors.

Comment: Wow thank you! But if I look at that I should maybe just run 24 queries instead of building a big one that I can't get to work because I don't understand :p Was just hoping that there is a LITTLE trick to do this. But thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

While I'm still not sure how you'd like to compare the start and end dates, looks like using `COUNT`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, and `HOUR`, you could come up with your desired results.

Possibly something similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), YEAR(Start), HOUR(Start), DAY(Start), MONTH(Start)
FROM Sessions
GROUP BY YEAR(Start), HOUR(Start), DAY(Start), MONTH(Start)
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfb62/6).

Comment: Hello, thank you for that but I don't think that this is the solution. The problem is that I have to check the endtime too to know if the session was active at a specific time.

See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e343d/1/0
Thats wrong because there should be 3, not 2.

Comment: What is your desired outcome?  I'm still not completely understanding.

Comment: Okay sorry. Lets take the last sqlfiddle. There are 3 sessions that were active at 17:00 so for the time XXXX 17:00 I want to see the value 3. If you think about user sessions then I simply want to know how many users were only at 01:00, 02:00 and so on.

Comment: @KarstenDetmold: Getting closer? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e328/5 -- might need some additional work for hours that roll over day to day, but should give you some ideas.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is another problem where the index table comes to the rescue.

An index table is something that everyone should have in their toolkit, preferably in the master database. It is a table with a single `id int primary key` indexed column containing sequential numbers from 0 to n where n is a number big enough to do what you need, 100,000 is good, 1,000,000 is better. You only need to create this table once but once you do you will find it has all kinds of applications.

For your problem you need to consider each hour and, if I understand your problem you need to count every session that started before the end of the hour and hasn't ended before that hour starts.

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/428aa/6)  for the solution.

What it does is use a known sequential number from the indextable (only 0 to 100 for this fiddle - just over 4 days - you can see why you need a big n) to link with your data at the top and bottom of the hour.